# MP4 - Many of my family videos are suddenly side by side and green

Tags: video, mp4

As mentioned in the title, many of my family videos are suddenly side by side and green. They are normal 2D videos. I don't understand why this happened, it is very sad since beautiful memories are now destroyed.

Is there a way to fix this and can someone explain how it happend? Is this a common problem?
The files are stored on a HDD as MP4. Some videos still work, but most are corrupted. No pictures are affected.

PS: Im not sure where else I can post this. If there is a better place to ask such questions, then please point me to it.

---

I tried it on Windows 10 with VLC Player.
I tried it with windows media player, but then it only plays the sound.

[image]

I tried it on another computer, it only shows a very zoomed in part of the video:

[image]

---

UPDATE: If I upload the video to youtube, then it works! So it must be some strange MP4 codec issue as 1NN mentioned in the comments.

Comment: This looks more like a codec or player issue. Have you tried a different video player? What format are the files? Also, try to [reset VLC to defaults](https://www.vlchelp.com/reset-vlc-hotkeys-preferences/)

Comment: Are you on Windows/Linux/Mac? What player are you using? What format are your videos?

Comment: I added more details. It is in MP4. If I try it on another computer I get a different weird result. But if I upload it to youtube, then it works!

Comment: Are those 3D videos? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc, no, normal 2D videos.

Comment: We need to see an example of one such video, to see if we can reproduce the problem on our side(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found is by using [VLC Media Player](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/) and convert the videos to MP4:

[image]

[Source](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-corrupt-videos/)

Alternatives:

1. create a youtube account, upload the videos (you can set them as private) and then download them. Delete them from youtube afterwards if you like.
2. Install a tool like **Wondershare Repairit** (costs money).